# DropDownListFor generates 'The name 'model' does not exist in the current context' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, razor

Just starting out using MVC3 and hit a problem trying to build a drop-down in a view.
The ViewModel is populated with a SelectList of items:

```
mdm.CaptionSetList=new SelectList(CaptionSet.Fetch(), "CaptionSetId", "Description")
```

which then is used in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Entity.CaptionSetId, model.CaptionSetList)
```

but when the page is hit, the line is highlighted with the compiler message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

What's the beginner's mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument for DropDownListFor is a function so that part is right, but the second part is just expecting a SelectList so all you need to do is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Entity.CaptionSetId, Model.CaptionSetList)
```

Note the capitalization.

**Further clarification**

In a strongly typed view `Model` is a property that refers to the model bound to the view. Since the second argument is just expecting a list and you've specified that the Model has a property called CaptionSetList, You specify the list as `Model.CaptionSetList`. If you had put the list in the `ViewBag`, you would put `ViewBag.CaptionSetList`.

Contrast this to the first argument which is a function that takes one argument of the same type as the model.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error.

In my case, I had done some search and replace and forgot to change the lambda expression:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => model.StagingDelegate.ManagerId, new[]{
             new SelectListItem() {Text = "ManagerId 1", Value = "1"},
             new SelectListItem() {Text= "ManagerId 2", Value= "2"},
             }, "Choose a Manager", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm " })
```

Replace m => with model =>:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StagingDelegate.ManagerId, new[]{
             new SelectListItem() {Text = "ManagerId 1", Value = "1"},
             new SelectListItem() {Text= "ManagerId 2", Value= "2"},
             }, "Choose a Manager", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm " })
```